# Elastic beanstalk http to redirect https not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy node app with on elastic beanstalk with loadbalance, I have configured elastic beanstalk https by using godaddy domain but its not working here is ACM issued list

[ACM View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKd6K.png)

Here is my loadbalance list

[Loadbalance list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NAqm.png)

Its not working on my go daddy domain with https but perfectly work on http elastic beanstalk domain. Please correct me what i a doing wrong here. I have followed the aws docs

Comment: What does it mean not working? Need to provide more detail information on what's happening.

Comment: I mean it's not running on HTTPS

Comment: This site can’t be reached. xxx.abc.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN @Marcin